# iOS scrollView setContentOffset "shimmy"

Tags: ios, uitextfielddelegate

I have a scrollView with multiple textFields, which tracks the active field and makes sure it is visible when the keyboard pops up. It all works well, but when I tab from the 3rd to 4th textField, I get a little up and down "shimmy" before the textField ends up in the right place. Any suggestions?

```
-(void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{    
    if (keyboardIsShown)return;

    NSDictionary* info=[notification userInfo];
    // get keyboard size
    CGSize keyboardSize=[[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]CGRectValue].size;
    //Set scrollview insets to make room for keyboard
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets=UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset=contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets=contentInsets;

    //scroll the active text field into view
    CGRect viewFrame=self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.size.height-=keyboardSize.height;
    int fieldHeight=self.currentTextField.bounds.size.height;
    CGFloat navHeight=self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    CGPoint viewPoint=CGPointMake(0.0, self.currentTextField.frame.origin.y+fieldHeight);

    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(viewFrame, viewPoint)) {
        //scroll to make sure active field is showing
        CGPoint scrollPoint=CGPointMake(0.0, viewPoint.y-keyboardSize.height+navHeight);//+navHeight
        [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}

-(void)showActiveField
{    
    //this makes sure that activeField shows when selecting another field after initial keyboard show
    int fieldHeight=self.currentTextField.bounds.size.height;
    CGPoint viewPoint=CGPointMake(0.0, self.currentTextField.frame.origin.y+fieldHeight);
    CGRect viewFrame=self.view.frame;

    int inset=scrollView.contentInset.bottom;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(viewFrame, viewPoint)) {
        //scroll to make sure active field is showing
        CGPoint scrollPoint=CGPointMake(0.0, viewPoint.y-inset);
        [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you set `keyboardIsShown`? Don't you want to do that Right after you check if it is already set?

And then: is the 4th field near the end of the scrollview and you have bounce scroll set?

Comment: I didn't use KeyboardIsShown, just KeyboardDidShow. Actually the KeyboardDidShow is not the problem. No matter which field is clicked on initially, when the keyboard appears, the scroll view scrolls smoothly to the correct spot. It's when subsequently clicking on the 3rd field that there is this stutter, going from the 3rd to 4th field(which is the first one hidden by the keyboard, that the stutter occurs. there is yet another field under it so i don't think it is the bounce.

Comment: I just added   scrollView.bounces=NO;, but it didn't affect this problem.

Comment: Your code says `if (keyboardIsShown)return;`. Where do you set that variable?